# ERROR:argument is missing, with no default

Tags: shiny, correlation

**I'm trying to create an Apps to calculate the coefficient  correlation but  is showing error messages. Could anyone help me?**

```
require(shiny)

F1<-c(1,3,15,-2,7,-18)

F2<-c(10,12,0,-3,5,-105)



shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Determination of Correlation Coefficient"),

  sidebarPanel(

wellPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "x_var",
              label = "X variable",
              choices = c("F1" = "F1", "F2" = "F2"),
              selected = "F1"
  )),



wellPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "y_var",
              label = "Y variable",
              choices = c("F1" = "F1","F2"="F2" ),
              selected = "F2"
  )),




  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
      tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
    )
  ) 
  )
  )
  )
```

Comment: Please fix your code properly, half of your code is not displayed as actual code

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. How "actual code"?

Comment: on stackoverflow, if you format your code properly, it will be displayed as such. There is a button for it in the editor. Yours wasn't entirely formatted.